# Select all vba on a specific sheet whilst looping through different workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have copied the same worksheet into multiple excel files, but it has an absolute reference to the original master sheet I copied from, so I would like to loop through the files and select all of the worksheet FinalResponse and find [Master.xlsm] and replace with ""

The below works but only finds the first instance of [Master.xlsm], then closes and saves, is there a way to make it find and replace all?

```
Sub findandreplace()
    '
    ' findandreplace Macro
    ' find and replace [Master.xlsm] with blank
    '
    
    '
    'this creates a collection of all filenames to be processed
    Dim loopFolder As String
    Dim fileNm As Variant
    Dim myFiles As New Collection
    
    '''don't forget the backslash before the final double-quote below
    loopFolder = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Response\"
    fileNm = Dir(loopFolder & "*.xlsx")
    
    Do While fileNm <> ""
        myFiles.Add fileNm
        fileNm = Dir
    Loop
    
    'this loops through all filenames and copies your copyWS to the beginning
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    For Each fileNm In myFiles
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=(loopFolder & fileNm))
        
        Sheets("FinalResponse").Select
        Selection.Replace What:="[Master.xlsm]", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart _
                                                                           , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                          ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
        Workbooks.Open(Filename:=(loopFolder & fileNm)).Save
        Workbooks.Open(Filename:=(loopFolder & fileNm)).Close
        
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple issues:

- Fully qualify your worksheets with the parent workbook.
- Avoid using `Select`.
- Don't call `Workbooks.Open` on an open file.

```
For Each fileNm In myFiles
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=loopFolder & fileNm)
    
    wb.Sheets("FinalResponse").UsedRange.Replace _
           What:="[Master.xlsm]", Replacement:="", _
           LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
Next
```

You don't need a separate collection for the filenames. You could open the file directly in your first loop:

```
loopFolder = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Response\"
fileNm = Dir(loopFolder & "*.xlsx")

Do While fileNm <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=loopFolder & fileNm)

    wb.Sheets("FinalResponse").UsedRange.Replace _
           What:="[Master.xlsm]", Replacement:="", _
           LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True    

    fileNm = Dir
Loop
```